# Vue Directive that creates a component and appends to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can i create a directive that appends another vue component to the element with the directive

For example:

```
<div :informable="myModel">
   <span>Some html</span>
</div>
```

would add an icon with information using the given model

**Update:**

To be more clear on what i want to do

```
<div :informable="myModel">
   <span>Some html</span>
</div>
```

would result to this:

```
<div>
   <span>Some html</span>
   <i>This is the information given from myModel</i>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want here. Maybe you can clarify with a more detailed example.

Comment: please explain your use case, maybe i could give a better idea since what you want is not enough clear

Comment: I have many many places in my application that i need to add an icon with a tooltip to the end of my element,  my tooltip is a component that has some functionality, and i want it show up only when the user hovers its parent element